# How to manage Firebase Authentication in Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, riverpod

I have a `firebase_providers.dart` file which looks like this:

```
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

final firebaseAuthProvider = Provider((ref) => FirebaseAuth.instance);

final authStateChangesProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<User?>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).authStateChanges();
});
```

It creates 2 simple providers - one for Firebase Auth instance and another for fetching current user status. I am using it on my main page like this:

```
class NavigationManager extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = useProvider(authStateChangesProvider);
    return user.when(
      loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: (error, stack) => Text('Error occured'),
      data: (user) {
        if (user == null) return LoginPage();
        return Dashboard();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is my basic setup for changing pages based on user auth status.

`LoginPage` is a stateful widget which contains the text fields, controllers etc.. In this file, I have the user email and password in `userEmail` and `userPassword`, now how to use it to log in a user? Official docs for [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage) uses this code:

```
UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "barry.allen@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
);
```

I can do it like this too but that wouldn't involve Riverpod. I need access to `firebaseAuthProvider` which contains `FirebaseAuth.instance`. To get access to this provider, I need to be inside a `HookWidget` to use `useProvider` but that would mean cluttering ui with logic. I would like to keep the logic separate in the same file where providers exist, i.e `firebase_providers.dart`

I also thought about doing something like this - converting `LoginPage` stateful widget to HookWidget and then getting access to `firebaseAuthProvider` and using it to call the sign in function which can reside in `firebase_providers.dart` but then how would I manage the form and text fields for which I created stateful widget in the first place?

So what is the way to manage and call all these auth functions like sign in, register etc.. using Riverpod?

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach is to create a service class that accepts a `ScopedReader` as a parameter.

For example:

```dart
class AuthService {
  const AuthService(this._read);

  final Reader _read;

  static final provider = Provider((ref) => AuthService(ref.read));

  Future<void> emailSignIn(String email, String password) async {
    final auth = _read(firebaseAuthProvider);
    final credential = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Then in your LoginPage:

```dart
class LoginPage extends HookWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async => context.read(AuthService.provider).emailSignIn(
            'barry.allen@example.com',
            'SuperSecretPassword!',
          ),
      child: Text('Login'),
    );
  }
}
```

This same pattern can be applied to repository classes using Firestore or other data providers.

Comment: What does `ref.read` in AuthService means?

Comment: `ref.read` behaves like `ref.watch` except it doesn't observe rebuilds when used to read a provider. It's a ScopedReader which is just like `context.read`. Passing it as a parameter to AuthService allows you to read providers without context.